# Add *.jar file in folder named Android Dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

[image]I want to use library from openCV named `"opencv library -2.4.3"` , I install all what it needs , and now openCV tutorials work. So I need add the same openCV library to my project for use.
QUESTION 
How to add opencv `"library -2.4.3"` from another project to mine's folder named `Android Dependencies`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to click on on the project properties (Right Click -> Properties) and add it as dependency there.

Answer (score 1):

Create a libs folder (/libs) in your project's root folder.
Copy the wanted jar to it.

It will be added to Android dependencies.

Comment: Nope, he have to click on on the project properties (Right Click -> Properties) and add it as dependency there.

Comment: It gives error "cannot paste the clipboard into the selected elements" , it gives almost same error when I tried to add it in the "Android dependencies" folder (same text without into the selected elements)

Comment: Hayk Nahapetyan - did you create the folder /libs in your project's root folder? Android dependencies is autogenerated you cannot copy thing to it. create the libs folder - > copy the jar to it and then clean and build your project

Comment: tell the truth @Leandros's way worked (Right Click-> properties -> Android , and then checking isLibrary checkbox, and adding it)

Comment: @Givi I didn't understood normaly , you mean folder named "libs" or "/libs" ?

Comment: just right click on your project in eclipse and select new->folder. Call this folder 'libs'.

Comment: I also have folder named "libs", I tried to past there but as I said it gives error  "cannot paste the clipboard into the selected elements" , but thank you very much for your response 
Dear @Leandros please live your comment like an answer, or I'll do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with a project, using eclipse 4.2.1.  As with the other answerer, all I had to do was create a folder called `"libs/"` in my project, and it auto-updated the Android Dependencies list.  Are you copying and pasting inside of eclipse?

I moved the file to that folder using the file system, outside of eclipse.

This link describes how the `libs` folder gets added to `Android Dependencies`:

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on project
2. Select Properties
3. Click on Android on left menu
4. Click on Add
5. Please select a Library Project

The jar will go into Android Dependencies.

If you add the jar directly to your project under libs or using build path, then it goes under Android Private Libraries.

Both methods works but referencing a library project can have benefits if you want to alter the code of the library during development.